# Powershell loop through unknown array key value pairs

Tags: arrays, powershell

How do i loop through an array of values into a format of Key, value pairs?

```
$a= Search-AzGraph -Query "Resources | project tags"

$a.tags[0]

Environment : Non-Production

Application : Openshift

AppOwner    : AzureOncall
```

End result should look like

```
Key                      Value

Environment              Non-Production

Application              openshift
```

Comment: `$a.tags[0] -replace ':', '=' | ConvertFrom-StringData`

Comment: What is $a?  Is it an array of PSCustomObjects?

Comment: @theo  after i use your command ,  results look as below  

'Name                           Value 
----                           -----
@{environment                  production; dataclassification=x; application=x; created_by=x; appowner=x; rnlcode=x}'

Comment: Then could you please tell us what `$a.tags[0].GetType().FullName` reveals, so we know what we're dealing with?

Comment: @theo $a.tags[0].GetType().FullName                                                                                                                  
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Comment: So, you you have an array of **PsCustomObjects** in `$a.tags`. Then why not send it out to a Csv file with `Export-Csv -Path 'Path\To\tags.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation`, so you can open in Excel as nice table? If you don't want all properties, you can use `Select-Object` first to display only the properties you need.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Theos Comment,you can use below

```
ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData $StringData -Delimiter ':'
```

Comment: Note that `-Delimiter` requires PS 7.0 at least.